# c# - How to compare strings with serialPort.ReadExisting()

Tags: c#, serial-port, string-comparison

Is there a way to compare **strings which are declared** with **received data from serial port** such as:

```
string hello = "hello";
string dataReceived = serialPort1.ReadExisting();  //the incoming data is "hello"
bool comparisonResult = hello.Equals(dataReceived, StringComparison.Ordinal);

if(comparisonResult == true)
{
    //do something
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? Are you sure the data is *exactly* 'Hello'?

Comment: @Rob Yeahp checked that i received exactly hello (case-sensitive too) but it still does not register that i have received "hello"

Comment: please check in the debugger, whether there are maybe spaces or extra characters like `\r` or `\n` in `dataReceived`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way

```
if (serialPort1.ReadExisting() == "hello")
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, displayed the received data to the textBox to check the data (which is "hello") but it somehow still does not register as serialPort1.ReadExisting() == "hello".

Answer (score 0):

Edit: found out why it didn't work, what i needed was culture-sensitive comparisons

```
string hello = "hello";
string dataReceived = serialPort1.ReadExisting();  //incoming data is "hello"
int comparisonResult = String.Compare(hello, dataReceived, true);
//if comparisonResult is true, output is 0

if (comparisonResult == 0)
{
     //do something
}
```

Comment: `String.Compare (a,b,true)` is a case insensitive comparison, not a culture-sensitive comparison.  If this works for you, then one of the strings must be something like "Hello" and the other "hello", which are different.

Comment: @MarkLakata [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx) I was very sure i was sending the same string case-wise, suspected that it may have something to do with the registers it uses to compare. Thanks anyways